# How to tell whether a given packet is subject to IPsec's SPD?

Tags: linux, networking, iproute, ipsec, strongswan

My IPsec configuration via strongSwan is non-device and uses XFRM policies / states.

On the VPN gateway I'm trying to test whether a given IP packet (described as src IP, src dev, dst IP) will be subject to XFRM policies or RIB/FIB. However, `ip route get ...` doesn't seem to consult XFRM policies and answers based on RIB.

Is there some other command that would give a better answer?